# Using Ruby #Split

Tags: ruby, string, scripting, split

I have a method, such as:

```
def change(string)
  return string
end
```

The method *change* will be called multiple times on an incoming stream of strings, such as:

```
1367 INFO sslsniff : Certificate Ready: test.neocal.info
1367 DEBUG sslsniff : New source 172.16.23.121:47864 <-> destination 54.241.163.174:443
1367 INFO sslsniff : Certificate Ready: test.neocal.info
1367 DEBUG sslsniff : New source 172.16.23.121:47882 <-> destination 54.241.163.174:443
1367 DEBUG sslsniff : New source 172.16.23.121:47883 <-> destination 54.241.163.174:443
1367 DEBUG sslsniff : New source 172.16.23.121:47884 <-> destination 54.241.163.174:443
```

I want to make *change* work so that anytime a line that contains *Certificate Ready: test.neocal.info* is read in, I want to alter it so that it returns the entire line, but it replacces '*test.neocal.info*' with the string '*voidparse*'.

My attempt was:

```
def change(string)
  arr = string.split(':')
  if arr[1] == " Certificate Ready"
    arr[2] == "nullvoid"
  end
  # it's this part i'm stuck--how can i rebuild the string with the modified array?
  return string
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub)

```
def change(string)
  string.gsub(/Certificate Ready: (.+)/, "Certificate Ready: voidparse")
end
```

If you prefer, you can also change the string inplace using `gsub!`

```
def change(string)
  string.gsub!(/Certificate Ready: (.+)/, "Certificate Ready: voidparse")
  string
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with something like :

```
def change(line)
  return line.gsub(/Certificate Ready: test.neocal.info/,"Certificate Ready:voidparse")
end
```

It will replace all occurences in the line, and return the resulting string.